# How to build react component for non react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I had built a react application using create-react-app project. Now I had to use some of the components from this project in non react application. So I will have to export those components alone in seperate js files which can be used in normal JS application (without webpack) by just referencing my js files and react library.

I tried ejecting from create-react-app and exported my component and related files as seperate chunk. Then I included those components in the target application through direct reference using "script" tag. After that I am not sure how I can mount my component as my components will be wrapped with some webpacks related export statement and in target application I am not using webpack or require js.

I googled and found nothing related to my case. Can someone through some light on this issue?

**[Update]**

When I say non react application it means currently the application is not using React or webpack. But ofcourse I will include the react library directly using script tag in a the page where I am going to include the components.

This question is mostly related to Webpack than React. I wanted to get the reference for the Components which is wrapped under webback related functions. If I could get that reference, then I know how to render the component using React library.

Comment: " non react application": In an angular or vue, AFAIK it is not possible to render that direactly to dom, without react or any other framework that does conversion from one to another one.

Answer (score 0):

[`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) can be leveraged to store variables you wish to share between imported scripts.

Although, it is important to be mindful not to pollute the namespace.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Window.components.
window.components = window.components || {}

// Component.
window.components.Component = props => <div>React Component</div>

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<window.components.Component/>, document.querySelector('#root'))

// Window Proof.
console.log(window.React, window.ReactDOM)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div>
  Regular HTML
  <div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to mount a component using ReactDOM.render function. My issue is how will I get the reference of my component? In your case you are using const Component = ******. For me I will have to get my component from my js file which is wrapped with some webpack related code. This is more of a question on webpack rather than react. Sorry if I am not clear in my initial question.

Comment: One solution might be to bind the variables you want to access more broadly to [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) @ShridharL

Comment: In angular you can just get the direct child. The wrapping component for Angular is available and very simple to write.

Comment: @ArmanCharan - Thank you for your reply. But I was expecting for some better and straight forward approach, as this component will be shared with other teams for them to use. And those teams wont be using NPM either. So basically they need a proper way to include my js files and use my components. Infact I was able to reference my components using a global variable named exports. But still I think this isn't an appropriate way of doing things. Their should be some better way of doing it.

Comment: Leveraging `window` is a fairly standard strategy. The `React` and `ReactDOM` scripts in the example above are bound to `window`. The trick is to package them neatly @ShridharL